# Querying BigQuery using Python, how does this Python table work?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

There's a guide that I followed to query BigQuery using Python from [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/articles/dashboard).

At the bottom, here's the code snippet that I'm confused about:

```
NameGeo = bqdata["schema"]["fields"][0]["name"]
NameVal = bqdata["schema"]["fields"][1]["name"]
table.add_column(NameGeo, unicode, NameGeo)
table.add_column(NameVal, float, NameVal)
for row in bqdata["rows"]:
    table.append(["US-"+row["f"][0]["v"], float(row["f"][1]["v"])])
```

I don't understand what this whole "`schema`" and "`field`" thing is...

I understand that they're columns, because I've changed it based upon what I need. However now I need to add an N number of columns, and I'm just not sure how I'd go about doing that!

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I'm a dummy, and was just searching for the wrong thing.

Found documentation that goes over everything I just asked. Doi.

For anyone else that's in the same boat [Here's the link to the BigQuery API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.jobs.html#query)

Comment: Thank you for posting your findings here! I would simply add that `bqdata` in the aforementioned example is essentially the Python-interpreted result of an API call to [Jobs: query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query) - the `name` property being the name of each field within the given schema as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query#schema.fields.name).